# Cannot use javafx.scene.control.DatePicker from Netbeans palette

Tags: java, netbeans, datepicker

I have added the `javafx.scene.control.DatePicker` class to my Netbeans palette, but any time I try to drag it into the design window, I get this error:

[Class Loading Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HqiO.png)

The upper portion of the exception is here:

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH9jc.png)

I have even added `DatePicker.class` to my `Source Packages` folder.  I have searched for related solutions, but this seems to be an uncommon issue or one not talked about very much.  I have verified that this happens for a new project, not just for my existing project.